# Force group of thumbnails within div to break lines

Tags: css, wordpress, line-breaks, nextgen-gallery

Simply put I have this page:

http://www.constantinos.org/portraits/

Each set of thumbnails is a NextGen Gallery and I want to make the galleries break lines if needed so they are not forced to appear as blocks in one line and the galleries will be next to each other instead of one per line.

An image is worth a thousand words so I photoshopped an example of I'd like to do:

http://constantinos.org/example/Screenshot%20from%202013-06-29%2018:01:23.png

this is my CSS for those sets of thumbnails:

```
#ngg-gallerySingleGallery {
float:left;
display: inline !important;
clear: none;
width: auto;
}
.ngg-gallery-thumbnail img {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 0;
display: block;
margin: 4px 0px 4px 5px;
padding: 4px;
position: relative;
}
```

Pfff. is doing my headings.. Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to accomplish? I'm having trouble understanding what you are describing.

Comment: @jackweinbender Thanks Jack, I want to have all the galleries arranged in a linear way following one another. See the photoshopped screen shot for a graphical example:  http://constantinos.org/example/Screenshot%20from%202013-06-29%2018:01:23.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok. so the problem is that you have your images grouped by threes in `ngg-galleryoverview` divs. So, even though they are floated, (both the images and the `ngg-galleryoverview` divs), your images will always be grouped in threes (You may need to review the box model a bit).

I don't know about how the galleries function—and this may be required markup for them to work properly—but that's *why* your images aren't flowing the way you want.

In fact, if you make your browser window **really** wide, you can see that the next three images will jump up to the first line.

So, I guess your best bet would be to place all the images into **one** gallery, rather than several smaller ones.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to achieve, prevent the galleries to be in groups of threes and have each thumbnails flow independently whilst still part of the gallery so they will follow a linear order like telling a story. Any ideas on how I can get this done?

Comment: I guess my question would be, *why do you need each line in a separate gallery?* My first instinct would be to put all of them into one big gallery (within one `ngg-galleryoverview` div. That way they will all flow nicely.

Comment: Hi Jack but they need to have a name, that's the reason why and have to be managed separately.

Comment: Again, you should probably go back and review the box model. Simply put, you can't do what you're asking with the markup that you're using. There may be a way to change the gallery JS or something, but that is outside the scope of this question.